# Can I put Drawable id in string.xml?

Tags: android

```
<string name="dm_icon">@drawable/qubic_icon</string>
```

While watching at my tutor's code, there was an red line error on

`@drawable/qubic_icon`

Is this a vaild xml code or not?

Or is there an alternative way to solve?

Comment: Why do you need to have drawable id in strings.xml?

Comment: I'm looking at legacy code with no explaination, and I'm having a hardship on understanding. And I don't know the code is lexically ok or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can store R.drawable.qubic_icon in Strings.xml as an int

```
<integer name="qubic_icon">R.drawable.qubic_icon</integer>
```

Comment: I've tried what you've said, but it shows an error.